# unexpected result when compare a float variable and an unsigned integer

Tags: c, keil, stm32f4

I have a strange and unexpected problem with a comparison of two variables in my C code. The code is wrote using Keil for STM32F407 micro-controller.
Please consider the following:

```
if ( f1 > u1 )
 {
  // do some ...
 }
```

f1 is a float variable and u1 is an unsigned integer.
In debug mode, f1=0.1 and u1=1600, but the if condition results true.

Can anybody solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `u1` should be implictly promoted to `float`. In normal circumstances condition should evaluate false. Something is missing here. Please create [mcve].

Comment: that `if` condition does ***not*** result in true. Is there something you are omitting to show us?  Please post a self-contained, compilable, verifiable sample.

Comment: @gst That is not duplicate. Assuming typical IEEE 754 implementation, precision issues are not the reason for problems here.